# Trying to make post request then get request

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js

In my code, I want to create a user (partner) and then after the post request has finished completely, get all the partners from an api (including the one just created) then access the Id of that partner to use in the rest of my code.

*PartnerName is also equal to whatever the user puts inside the form that posts here

```
    await axios
      .post(newPartnerUrl, { Name: PartnerName }, options)
      .then(async () => {
        const partnersRes = await axios.get(getPartnersUrl, options);
        const partners: IPartner[] = partnersRes.data;
        partners.map((partner: IPartner) => {
          if (partner.Name === PartnerName) {
            partnerId = partner.Id
          }
        });
      });

    const PartnerId = partnerId
```

This is the code, could anybody help to make it work and/or more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you should fully use `async/await` instead of mixing it with `then`. After that, you can use `find` to get the latest partner according to `PartnerName`.

```
async function addPartner() {
    await axios.post(newPartnerUrl, { Name: PartnerName }, options);

    const partnersRes = await axios.get(getPartnersUrl, options);
    const partners: IPartner[] = partnersRes.data;
    //find the newly added partner
    const newPartner = partners.find((partner: IPartner) => partner.Name === PartnerName);

    const PartnerId = newPartner.id

    //TODO: You can do something else with the newly added partner
}
```

Comment: Thanks the filter is helpful, I agree with not mixing them. I think the issue is the partner is being created after the get request since its taking too long. would it be possible to delay the get request for a few seconds?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot get the partner data from GET? @max14

Comment: the GET request is fine, i've just debugged through and the post request hasn't completely finished when the GET is called, therefore it's not finding the user

Comment: I see. I guess the above solution can help you out because it will wait for POST completed and then it will run GET @max14

Comment: I've tried the above solution, I think the request has gone through but I think its taking a few more seconds to create the partner in the database

Comment: did you check POST document? In some cases, POST will return your latest data. In that case, you don't need to call GET @max14

Comment: no, its my own api and the post doesnt return the result

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, turns out the partner wasn't being added to the database at the time of the get request so I've added a timeout for 2 seconds which allows the partner time to be added.

for anyone with this issue as well here is the code

```
function delay(n){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(resolve,n*1000);
    });
}
```